# javascript prompt sent to php but output empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to allow adding of a category to category dropdownlist by clicking the '+' button below it using ajax but my dropdownlist keeps disappearing instead.

HTML codes are as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<script>
function addCategory()
{
var category = prompt("Please enter new category: ", "");

if (category != null){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){// && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","add_category.php?category="+category,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include ('db_conn.php');
session_start();

if(!empty($_REQUEST['event'])){
    $event = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM `COO_DEF_EVENT` WHERE EVENT_ID = :eventid;");

    try{
        $event->bindParam(':eventid', $_REQUEST['event']);

        $event->execute();

        $eventdet = $event->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Error getting event data';
    }

    echo '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="editEvent.php">';
}else{
    echo '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addEvent.php">';
}
?>  
Category:
<div id="category"><select name="categorydpl" id="categorydpl">
              <?php       
              $categorySQL = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM `CATEGORY` WHERE USER_ID = :userid; ");

                try{
                    $categorySQL->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION["userid"]);

                    $categorySQL->execute();

                    $categoryList = $categorySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach ($categoryList as $category){
                        echo '<option value="'.$category['CATEGORY_ID'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($category['CATEGORY_NAME']).'</option>';
                    }

                }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    echo 'Error getting data';
                }
                ?>
            </select></div><button onClick="addCategory()">+</button>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"
                value="Submit" /><button onClick="location.href ='index.php';">Cancel</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
include ('db_conn.php');
session_start();

$category = $_GET['category'];
$print='category entered: '.$category;

$sql = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `COO_CATEGORY` (`USER_ID`, `CATEGORY_NAME`) VALUES (:userid, :category_name);");

try{
    $sql->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION["userid"]);
    $sql->bindParam(':category_name', $category);

    $sql->execute();

}catch (PDOException $ex){
echo 'Insertion failed. Please try again';
}

 $categorySQL = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM `COO_CATEGORY` WHERE USER_ID = :userid;");

try{
    $categorySQL->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION["userid"]);

    $categorySQL->execute();

    $categoryList = $categorySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $print .= '<select name="categorydpl" id="categorydpl">';
    foreach ($categoryList as $category){
    $print.= '<option value="'.$category['CATEGORY_ID'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($category['CATEGORY_NAME']).'</option>';
}
$print.='</select>';

}catch(PDOException $ex){
echo 'Error getting data';
}
echo $print;
?>
```

When I open the php by typing .../add_category.php?category=sad

The page will display

"category entered: sad " followed by a dropdown list with sad inserted.

But when I try with the html file, the dropdownlist will disappear after I click the plus button and enter any value.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you checked what the response is of the xmlhttp call using Firebug or something of the like?

Comment: I just tried using that on firefox. But it doesn't show anything. I think it is because I am just redirected to error page everytime. I am testing on 000webhost.com.

Comment: If it's not showing anything, then the call is just not being made, which is strange because your div#category is being updated. Can you Console.log() the response text? Also, check out the firebug network tab, it's perfect for debugging these kind of issues: http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Ok, I tried again and checked the network tab. Under  .../add_category.php?category=sad, under params tab, it shows category sad

Comment: Well, then you should trace the xmlhttp.responseText, see what that exact value is. Also, why do you have the "&& xmlhttp.status==200" part commented out?

Comment: when i do not comment out "&& xmlhttp.status==200", nothing happens at all. I edited the codes. I missed out the form part which I added and uploaded but did not save in my computer apparently. Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: I tried checking xmlhttp.responseText but adding alert(xmlhttp.responseText); into the js, and got got a blank alert. But I don't get why since when I load the php on it's own, it works.

Comment: My last comment on this: leave the 200 status check in, its good practice. Check the network tab to see what status code comes back if it isn't 200, this should lead you to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with jQuery. In html file

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'add_category.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'category' : category},
            success:
                function(answer){
                    $('#categorydpl').empty();
                    answer && answer.forEach(function(entry){
                        $('#categorydpl').append(new Option(entry['id'], entry['name']));
                    })
                },
            error: 
                function(){
                    console.log('Error');
                }
        }
      );
```

and in your php file

```
$categoryList = $categorySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($categoryList as $category){
    $result[] = array('id' => $category['CATEGORY_ID'], 'name' => htmlspecialchars($category['CATEGORY_NAME']));
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: But if jQuery isn't included already, it is a bit overkill when vanilla js will do.

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons submit forms. Submitting a form will reload the page.

Use `<button type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not doing a cross-site request (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). When calling a page on a different domain with an ajax call, the browser doesn't allow it by default as a security measure.

Comment: xmlhttp.status is 0 and I checked those with this same problem and most occur when status is 0 is cross-site request. But all my files are on the same server, domian, folder.

Comment: Double check that they are, and try replacing everything with absolute urls, just to be sure.